# Facebook Logout is not working in new SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, safari, facebook-ios-sdk

Each time get authorized screen of user. I am not able to login with different user.I think issue is, safari stores cookies.

This may have bug in Facebook SDK.

Answer (score 6):

**1. Clear to facebookToken**

```
 FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(nil)
 FBSDKProfile.setCurrentProfile(nil)
```

**2. Logout FBSDKLoginManager.**

```
let manager = FBSDKLoginManager()
manager.logOut()
```

**NOTE : its logout from apps if you choose FBSDKLoginBehavior is web that open Facebook Login page in UIWebView., if you choose Native then open Facebook Login page in safari browser and store data in safari.**

```
let loginView : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()
loginView.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web
```

Comment: Thank you..FBSDKLoginBehavior.Web fixed my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to import `FBSDKLoginKit` and then:

```
 FBSDKAccessToken.setCurrentAccessToken(nil)
 FBSDKProfile.setCurrentProfile(nil)

let manager = FBSDKLoginManager()
manager.logOut()
```

Answer (score -1):

Open Safari, go to facebook.com website and logout. I think it's the 6th tab from the top in the mobile website, the logout option is at the bottom.

EDIT:

> Reading safari cookies from third party applications is not possible,
> rather it would put the user privacy in pitfalls. As of now, this
> could be the possible way to login with different credentials at
> times.
>
> And [FBSDKAccessToken setCurrentAccessToken:nil];  this can be
> just resets the sdk's accesstoken to nil, which enables the 'Logout'
> to 'Login with Facebook' and relaunches the safari facebook authroizing when it's clicked again.

Comment: I want to do logout safari from my app only.